# Is it possible to create a formatted list or manifest of all photos in my Photos library?

Tags: backup, photos, photos.app

I would like to compare two different instances of the Photos libraries, then export only the files that are different and merge into a single library.  I know it is possible to export all from one library and then import all to another, but you end up with duplicates.  If the libraries are similar it could be a lot of duplicates and wasted storage space.  It would be helpful to create a manifest of each library, and diff the manifests.

Thanks!